# Custom Settings in salesforce

Tags: customsetting

What is the use of Custom settings in salesforce,I have created the Custom setting in Hiearchy type and add a new Custom field Called Account1,After that where i have to use this Custom setting,How to implement the Custom settings in salesforce, why we Need field in Custom settings in salesforce,what is the use of field,I have uploaded the image,please anayone explain the custom setting with example

Comment: what i have created from above field , with the use of these fields please anyone Explain with Example

Comment: As is, your question is very broad. Have you made any attempt to research this question before asking it? A quick google search should turn up plenty of results, including some use cases for both List and Hierarchy Custom Settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Custom Settings**

Use custom settings to create custom sets of data, or to create and associate **custom data for an org, profile, or user**.

Custom settings are similar to custom objects in that they let you customize org data. Unlike custom objects which have records based on them, custom settings let you utilize custom data sets across your org, or distinguish particular users or profiles based on custom criteria.

Custom settings data is exposed in the application cache, which enables efficient access without the cost of repeated queries to the database. This data can then be used by formula fields, validation rules, flows, Apex, and the SOAP API.

**Hierarchy Custom Settings**

A type of custom setting that uses a built-in hierarchical logic that lets you “personalize” settings for specific profiles or users. The hierarchy logic checks the organization, profile, and user settings for the current user and returns the most specific, or “lowest,” value. In the hierarchy, settings for an organization are overridden by profile settings, which, in turn, are overridden by user settings.

The following examples illustrate how you can use custom settings:

1. A shipping application requires users to fill in the country codes for international deliveries. By creating a list setting of all country codes, users have quick access to this data without needing to query the database.
2. An application calculates and tracks compensation for its sales reps, but commission percentages are based on seniority. By creating a hierarchy setting, the administrator can associate a different commission percentage for each profile in the sales organization. Within the application, one formula field can then be used to correctly calculate compensation for all users; the personalized setting at the profile level inserts the correct commission percentage.
3. An application displays a map of account locations, the best route to take, and traffic conditions. This information is useful for sales reps, but account executives only want to see account locations. By creating a hierarchy setting with custom checkbox fields for route and traffic, you can enable this data for just the “Sales Rep” profile.

[Reference](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=cs_about.htm)